# How to insert upload table primary key(ID) to info table (ID) at the same time?

Tags: php, mysql

Info table query:

```
CREATE TABLE `info` (
  `id_info` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `judul_info` varchar(50) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `konten` varchar(255) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `diubah_oleh` varchar(20) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `id_kategori` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `tgl_buat` timestamp NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `tgl_ubah` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `dibuat_oleh` varchar(20) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id_info`),
  KEY `id_kategori` (`id_kategori`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=62 ;
```

Upload table query :

```
CREATE TABLE `upload` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `deskripsi` text,
  `filetype` varchar(200) default NULL,
  `filedata` longblob,
  `filename` varchar(200) default NULL,
  `filesize` bigint(20) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=34 ;
```

i want to insert the upload.id same as info.id when i post a new info. please help me.
here's my source code(sorry for the query i can't upload an image cause of my reputation still low):

```
<?php
include "config.php";

$id_info=$_POST['id_info'];
$judul=$_POST['judul_info'];
$konten=$_POST['konten'];
$tgl_ubah=$_POST['tgl_ubah'];
$diubah_oleh=$_POST['diubah_oleh'];
$id_kategori=$_POST['id_kategori'];

// update data in mysql database 
$sql="UPDATE info SET judul_info='$judul', konten='$konten', diubah_oleh='$diubah_oleh', id_kategori='$id_kategori' WHERE id_info='$id_info'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully updated. 
if($result){
echo "Telah diupdate";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='list_info.php'>View result</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the **last_insert_id()** or **mysql_insert_id()** after your insert into the info table to get the new id inserted and then then use that in your next query while inserting record into upload table. Refer to links below on how to use them.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-function.mysql-insert-id.html
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id